# Linked List Node object

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Node* node1 = new Node(12);
    
    cout<< node1->data ;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can't understand that why are we creating pointer object for the node (Node* node1)?

Thanks for clearing my doubt in advance

Comment: There is no point to it. It would be better for it to not be a pointer.

Comment: We create that so we can do a basic test. nothing in `main` is part of the linked list. `main` is only for demonstrating it works.

Comment: Your sample program looks like an example of how to allocate and access a `Node` object. It's like "Hello, world" for Nodes. There seems no point to it now, but likely you'll use the knowledge soon when it comes to working with multiple nodes that are strung together in a linked list.

Comment: Linked list is a "Hump Mission" for new programmers that washes out a lot of them. It's good to see people easing into it.

Comment: Side note: In many cases the constructor would be better as `Node(int data): data(data), next(nullptr) { }`. It doesn't matter much for `int`s and pointers, default initialization for them is to do nothing, but because all base classes and members must be initialized before entering the body of the constructor there is often a duplication of work initializing the member and then assigning it the correct value inside the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `main()` needs a pointer simply because that is what `new` returns.  The code is creating the `Node` object in *dynamic* memory on the heap (and consequently leaking it, since there is no `delete node1;` statement before the `return` statement).

You could instead create the object in *automatic* memory on the stack, and thus not need a pointer, eg:

```
int main()
{
    Node node1(12);
    
    cout << node1.data;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Typically, linked lists are created using dynamic memory so that new nodes can be added to the list dynamically, such as in a loop, or in response to user input, etc.